# Unable to setup a static ip address on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

This is the netplan config I've been attempting to use:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.70.79/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.70.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

Using a static ip completely kills my computer's internet connection, even after rebooting. It timeouts at any attempts to ping google. What am I doing wrong?

Note, my dynamically given ip address before this was 192.168.70.79

EDIT: I fixed it. Albeit, my solution was a bit roundabout. I ended up installing Ubuntu Desktop onto the system so I could see what default IP settings it gave me, and was able to use those to get a static IP working. I then reinstalled Ubuntu Server and everything was smooth sailing from there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. I am glad you solved the problem. However, please don't put the answer inside the question. Please click the **Answer Your Own Question** button below to write your answer. Later you should accept the correct answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should work.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
      - 172.168.70.79/24
      dhcp4: false
      routes:
      - to: default
      via: 192.168.70.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
```

The indentations are important!

Also check in bash with

```
ip address
```

what name your network device has. If it's not enp4s0 adjust your config.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. And yes, enp4s0 seems to be the correct device name.

Comment: can you post output of "ip address"